# PayPal Refund API Operation getting error 520002

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to write in bash the code the partial refund paypal transaction. This is the guide I am following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/ but I'm receiving a 520002 error message. In previous request I've seen that it's needed to specify `receiverList.receiver(0).email` but it's still not working.
This is what my request look like:

```
curl -s --insecure
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: your_app_id "          
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Refund  -d  
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US 
&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll
&transactionId=xxxxxxxxxx
&receiverList.receiver(0).email=xxxxxxxx
&currencyCode=EUR
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=44.00"
```

Anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: Could you try removing the 'transactionId' parameter, and add 'payKey' parameter instead? Set the 'payKey' parameter to the paykey used for the original payment

Comment: Please provide th completed API response for further research. In addition, please make sure the transaction is an adaptive payment transaction, not Express checkout transaction or standard transaction.

Comment: Hi Zhao, we have implemented the Express checkout for the transactions. Then what used for the refund cannot work correct? Can you please help me figuring out what is the correct guide to follow? Many thanks for the help.

Comment: If the transaction is a Express checkout payment, you need to use this API to refund money: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong API for this.
Your endpoint goes to the Adaptive Payments API which is used for very specific business case and is very complicated to implement.

If you want to make a simple refund from a payment made with PayPal Express Checkout or PayPal Standard you should use the **RefundTransaction** API call.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_basicRefund-curl-etc/

You CURL call should be like this:

```
Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
HTTP method: POST
POST data:
USER=merchant_user_name
&PWD=merchant_password
&SIGNATURE=merchant_signature
&METHOD=RefundTransaction
&VERSION=94
&TRANSACTIONID=transaction_ID    #ID of the transaction for which the refund is made 
&REFUNDTYPE=Full    #Specifies a full refund; a partial refund requires more input fields
```

Comment: Many thanks for the support. Now I'm receiving this error:
TIMESTAMP=2016%2d03%2d01T17%3a15%3a35Z
&CORRELATIONID=3c778604ba343&ACK=Failure
&VERSION=94&BUILD=18316154
&L_ERRORCODE0=10002
&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error
&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

The call I made is this:

curl -v --data "USER=my username
&PWD=mypassword
&SIGNATURE=merchant_signature
&METHOD=RefundTransaction
&VERSION=94
&TRANSACTIONID="$tId"
&REFUNDTYPE=Full" 
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

Comment: The security header error shows when your credentials are wrong. Check you are using the right endpoint (sandbox or live) and that your API credentials are right.